# Create API Call function from url

Tags: php, api

Someone in my company has provided me this url to demonstrate an API `status` response:

```
http://www.filmon.com/affiliate-api/status?app_id=123&app_secret=123&affid=44dh
```

The required pieces are `app_id` and `app_secret`, then `affid` to test the status.

My question: how can I create a PHP function that will perform this same action? (i.e. I need PHP function to get this exact same response, but don't know how)...

Any help would be great!

Comment: You need curl. http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0):

Create an `status.php` file, and then use `$_GET[ 'app_id' ]`, `$_GET[ 'app_secret' ]` and `$_GET[ 'affid' ]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.filmon.com/affiliate-api/status?app_id=123&app_secret=123&affid=44dh");    

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

`$response` contains what is returned from the API.

Comment: this is good, although it actually shows HTML when I use `print_r($response);`  Is there a way to get the actual response?

Comment: add user agent option. Edited the answer.